# Bookmarks for the close -> duplicate interface

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

Most of the times, when I close a question as duplicate, I open a new tab to make a quick google search to get the question ID, to then close the question.

I almost never find the duplicate, which I think fits the best in the similar question list, nor do I find it when I use the search bar there:

[image]

---

So I propose as a feature request to implement "bookmarks for the close -> duplicate interface". As you can already bookmark questions which you like, I think it could be really helpful if you can bookmark questions, which you use often as duplicate and you can view them right in the closing interface.

So these bookmarks would be separated from your normal bookmarks and you can open/view them right in the closing interface, e.g.

[image]

You then can click on the arrow to open a window to the right, where you then have all your bookmarked duplicate questions, which you can search by tags.

So it would be a lot more efficient to close a question and you wouldn't always have to open a new tab to make a google search. You would already have your bookmarked duplicate questions right there, just a little scroll and you can close the question with the duplicate.

It wouldn't change the world, but I think it would be a little improvement, which would help to close a question easier with the duplicate, which you have in your mind.

Comment: Aside: You are trying to close when you have 0 votes remaining :P

Comment: TBH, that's why I bookmark/favorite questions anyway most of the time but it would be a nice way to separate them out.

Comment: @Paulie_D I think another advantage is, that you have them right there where you need them and don't have to open a new tab go to your favorite list and search there. And as already said in my question, it should be possible to filter them by tags, so if you have a lot of questions bookmarked you can filter them, e.g. `[php][arrays]` and then you find them still fast even if you have a lot of questions in this list.

Comment: I think centralized lists of dupe targets for each (major) tag makes more sense than everyone having their own lists. But maybe individual lists could work if the system software could do some sort of correlation on the individual lists.

Comment: Maybe allow us to privately tag a favorite question: `common-duplicate`; `recent-activity`; `brilliant-code`; `current-project`; and `future-project` seem to be why I commonly "favorite" a question.

Comment: @Teepeemm I don't think we need sub categories for bookmarks on  Stack Overflow, since I think this is more something personal, which you might want to do for your own, like having a simple list with these questions.

Comment: I'm not sure how a "centralized list of dupe targets" would work...isn't that *every question on SO*? The existing related questions etc. reference algorithm don't seem to find the right questions on a consistent basis so I'm not confident that any centralized list could be accurate.

Comment: @Paulie_D: A list sounds like something tangible. It could be managed explicitly by silver-badge holders - instead of being some detail of an arbitrary algorithm that needs tuning.

Comment: @Bergi ...I confess I'm not sure what you meant but I already *have* a list. It's my favourites (currently). They are specific to me (obviously) and in areas in which I have (I think) I have some expertise. So a separate *personal* list that is available *only to me* when I want to mark something as duplicate seems the most logical.

Comment: @Paulie_D: I see (but notice that [favourites are not as private as you might think](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites:2802040)). But if we had a list for duplicates, I think *sharing* the entries is quite important.

Comment: @Bergi True (not that I mind if my favourites are private or not)..but if I have no knowledge of PHP. C++ etc then I don't need or want those options so they are of little or no value to me.  As long as there is a reasonably efficient filter on this master list them I suppose it could work but linking my private list  provides an *automatic* filter for me.

Comment: @Paulie_D: As Bergi suggests, I'm thinking of something that utilizes human knowledge & experience to enhance the current system of dupe targets being suggested by an algorithm that (presumably) works by simple keyword / pattern-matching and vote counting. I don't (yet) have a clear idea how to implement this, which is why this stuff is in comments rather than an answer. :)

Comment: (cont) Perhaps all we need is a simple system where we all have our own personal dupe target lists but the system software lets us know which of our targets are popular, in the sense of them being on other tag experts dupe lists. However, I think for maximum effectiveness we also need some way to give those questions / answers some sort of score re: their merit as a dupe target for a particular topic. But I guess that could get rather tricky to implement effectively.

Comment: This is somewhat implemented: `infavorites:mine [tag] score:high`. Now you just need to favorite those targets.

Comment: for a list of [meta-tag:canonical] dupe targets in particular tag, storing them in respective [meta-tag:tag-wiki] looks worth considering. It's easy to access, maintain and share (see eg [c++](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) and [scala](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info) tag wiki)

Comment: @Paulie_D: _"I'm not sure how a "centralized list of dupe targets" would work"_ -- yes, the entire site is the list of potential dupe targets. But of course, for any given tag, only a subset is. More to the point, for many of the tags (maybe all of them...I only follow a few so I can't speak broadly) there are a _small_ subset of questions that come up repeatedly. For example, I would expect most languages to have a canonical "null reference" dupe target (for sure [c#] and [java] do). I can see how having an easy way to access that small list of common dupe targets would be useful.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I totally agree. I've felt for a while that there should be a (wiki?) page for each of the major language tags that has a list of link to canonical questions/answers for often seen dupes. Speaking from a Python perspective "Why isn't my dictionary ordered?", "Why is my list `None` (`list = list.sort()`) and one that is seen in probably every language "Python's math is wrong, `.1 + .2 == .3` is False" are all questions that come up everyday and like clockwork people rush in to answer them while I look for a dupe. Some of them even start getting upvoted.

Comment: As an alternative or corollary to the proposal here, I think what a lot of people would agree on is that for the most popular tags, it would probably make sense for Stack Overflow to host an actual **FAQ** page. The SO model has improved on some, but not all of the features we used to have before web forums (i.e. in mailing lists and newsgroups). One stark lack is that of an FAQ. Ironically, SO _could_ do that _better_, i.e. by actually _requiring_ someone to at least visit the FAQ page before posting in that tag, and even possibly to do some matching between a question and topics in an FAQ.

Comment: In case it's not obvious: in the SO model, the FAQ page would not in itself generally have actual answers, except possibly for the simplest ones. Instead, it would have a short discussion of each FAQ, along with one or more links to the canonical or otherwise dominant SO question(s) that answer that FAQ.

Answer (score -8):

Browsers already have a bookmark feature, and most - if not all - browsers support copying the URL of a bookmark without opening it (right click -> copy). The close interface already allows inputting URL's. So yes, it takes a couple of clicks, but especially using a folder in the bookmarks toolbar would be pretty efficient

1. click (open the folder)
2. scroll (find the question)
3. right click (open context menu)
4. click (copy)
5. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> (duplicate field)
6. <kbd>enter</kbd> (vote to close)

vs

1. click (to bookmarks instead of similar suggested questions)
2. scroll (find the question)
3. click (open the question in preview)
4. click (vote to close).

So yes, it would indeed be marginally more efficient to have a dedicated duplicate bookmark interface, but for such a specialized request I think the current 'input URL'-feature and dedicated bookmark support in browsers is already quite definitely up to the task (not that I am against SE implementing the feature, all I am saying is that if this workflow is so important to you that you can get quite similar efficiency with a lot more control (as you can organize your bookmarks in a lot more ways than SE would allow)).

---

And just in case you go through Google a lot, here are the relevant keyboard shortcuts to optimize that workflow a bit (I expect them to be well known, but considering you're bringing this up as a feature request I thought it would be valuable to include)

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>
2. Enter search qeury
3. Click result (likely first, so no dedicated scroll action)

   - if you wish to do it with the keyboard <kbd>down</kbd> and then <kbd>enter</kbd> works too
4. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> (jump to location bar)
5. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> (copy URL)
6. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> (close tab and jump back to SO duplicate interface)
7. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> (paste in duplicate field)
8. <kbd>enter</kbd> (vote to close)

Comment: Your solution of bookmarking things locally fails when you consider that a single person might use multiple machines and browsers. And while syncing bookmarks is possible, it's not always practical or allowed; e.g. on work machines due to IT restrictions. It also means everybody has to create that bookmark list by themselves - I rather like the suggestion by PM2 Ring that there should be a centralized list of dupe targets for at least the major tags. This could be either provided by the community or maybe just autogenerated from the most used dupe targets.

Comment: @l4mpi I totally agree that a centralized dupe target list (or simply the question list with the most dupes per major tag) would be quite interesting, but that's quite a separate proposal from the one under consideration here. Additionally "everybody" is just the small subset of users who wish to have a private bookmark list as per OP.